# JavaScript failing when parsing XML that has blanks in nodeValues?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have an application that uses Javascript to parses a XML array that is returned from a Webservice and iterates through it and builds it into a table body. It has been working with no issues until lately.

We had some changes on the database that the Webservice is returning results from in which now there are a few columns that could potentially have blanks or null values.

The Javascript fails to run when it hits a childNode that has a blank or null value.

Below is a snapshot of the browser error:
[image]

So my question is how do I handle those blanks so that the Javascript will just build an empty string into the table body and continue iterating through the xml array?

I have tried to build an if statement into the Javascript in the for loop to replace the blank or null value with '', but I'm not sure it's going to be doable with the way my table body is being built.

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
tbody += "<tr><td class=col1>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("CheckInDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  +
"</td><td class=col2>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("CheckOutDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td class=col3>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("CheckInOut")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("address")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("names")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("companyName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.substr +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("contactPhoneNum")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td ></tr >";
}
```

Being as how this is an existing application I don't want to rebuild all the functions that build tables using this method so I hope there is an easy solution to this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: What does "fails to run" mean? Are errors reported?

Comment: please share the browser console error, and I suggest you to use map with join or reduce to have this html string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.childNodes` will be `null` if the XML element doesn't have any content (any text nodes). You seem to have a lot of repeating code, to fix this you can create a function to get the content of an XML node with a specific tag name if it has any content or return an empty string.

Here is an example:

```
function getElementContent(element, tagName) {
  const e = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  if (e && e.childNodes && e.childNodes.length) {
    return e[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
  }
  return '';
}

const tbody = x.map(e => `<tr><td class=col1>${getElementContent(e, 'CheckInDate')}</td><td class=col2>${getElementContent(e, 'CheckInDate')}..... `).join('');
```

Comment: Titus, 

That makes total sense and I understand your example. Where it gets tricky for me is I have this nested in a for loop that is iterating through the entire array and building out the tbody. Your suggestion only grabs one record, but I guess I can keep it in the for loop and just call your function over and over until the loop is finished.

Comment: @ChisumTrail My example loops through all the elements of `x`. I've edited my answer to make `tbody` a string instead of an array of strings.